# Can't find server explorer Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, server-explorer

I'm trying to make a C# application and I need the server explorer but I can't find it when I click on View menu. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015. Is it disabled or did I do something wrong?

[image: View]

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question about why it is missing, but the shortcut key combo is `Ctrl+Alt+S`.

Comment: Did you check under "Other Windows"?

Comment: @RizJa Thanks a lot! The database explorer is.

Answer (score 1):

If it is missing you can modify your View menu using the following instructions:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Go to **Tools > Customize...**
3. Click the **Commands** tab
4. Select **View** from the *Menu Bar* dropdown (make sure the *Menu Bar* radio button is selected)
5. Scroll down the menu window until you see *Solution Explorer* and select it.
6. Click the **Add Command...** button
7. Scroll down the *Categories* list and select **View**
8. Scroll down the resulting *Commands* list and select **Server Explorer**
9. Click the **OK** button

Answer (score 0):

### The Bad

If you double click on the solution (SLN) file, the result is this.

[image: first]

If you close the solution, the result is this.

[image: second]

### The Good

If you close Visual Studio 2015, and then just run it without opening any solution, the result is this.

[image: third]

### The Ugly

1. Click on File,
2. Open,
3. Project/Solution,
4. Browse to your solution's folder,
5. Select the solution file,
6. Click the Open button.

There you go! You will now find it under the View menu. I have a screenshot to prove it.

[image: fourth]

### About

Just a little something for posterity.

> Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01
>   Update 3 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02046
>
> Installed Version: Blend
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0
>
> NuGet Package Manager   3.5.0

Running on Windows 10.0.15063 (64-bit).